# Exclude information from bibliography

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, citing, biber

I am using .bib-files for my citations at my university and want to restrict my bibliography printed in my compiled pdf to exclude certain information.

For example I have this entry in my bibliography:

```
@book{genmoral1887,
author      = "Friedrich Nietzsche",
title       = "Zur Genealogie der Moral",
address     = "Stuttgart",
publisher   = "Reclam",
year        = "1988",
note        = "[1887]"
}
```

When the bibliography is printed, all the information is printed out onto the pdf. The problem is that I want to exclude the note-attribute as it contains the year, the book was originally published in by the author. I want to keep this information in my bibliography (to look it up in case I forget) and add other information like the isbn, to have an easier time researching books and articles I already used, but to format it correctly, I want to specify, which parts of the bibliography-entry to exclude when compiling.

Is there a way to do this in my .tex file for example with the style of the bibliography? I can't find anything except different styles concerning how, not which information is displayed.

Comment: I normally just go through the `.bib` using a text editor and then rename the keys I don't want, for example here we could rename `note` to `OPTnote`, the bibliography style has no idea what to do with `OPTnote` and thus ignores it.

Comment: with bibtex the default is to ignore all fields, so unless you are using a bibliography style that explicitly includes notes it will be excluded. You can always use a definitely non-standard field such as mynote=... which will be ignored by all bib styles

Comment: Okay, I just found out, that there is a workaround to give the note a name, the compiler doesn't recognize. E.g. instead of printing `note = "[1887]` I could write `EXCEPTnote = "[1887]` into my .bib-file. This is not what I originally wanted, as it is only a workaround and I have to reedit the .bib-file every time I want to change, what information is displayed, but it somehow works. Still not what I was looking for.

EDIT: While I was typing, others had the same idea.

Comment: If the note is appearing then you are using a bib style that uses notes, so the alternative is to use a different style if you do not want to edit the bib file, but as you have not said which style you are using (or even if you are using bibtex rather than biber) it is hard to give specific advice

Comment: I am very sorry for that, I am using `authoryear-ibid` in my preamble:
`\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}`

Comment: I think [`biblatex`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex) has options to alter or remove certain fields; I guess it is done via `biber`. If you add `\DeclareSourcemap{\maps[datatype=bibtex]{ ... }}`, you can modify certain fields in certain class of documents like `article`, `book`, `inproceedings`. See the [`biblatex` manual](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex), section 4.5.3 on page 196.

Comment: For instance, if I wanted to remove the filed `note` from books, I'd add the following declaration to a preamble:
`\DeclareSourcemap{
\maps[datatype=bibtex]{
\map{\pertype{book}
\step[fieldset=note, null]
}
}`. Again, you would have to change to use `biblatex` with `biber`.